# Why does this sentence sounds weird?

Tags: grammar, american-english, syntactic-analysis

I applied to a summer program and the email stated that I was deferred.

> We are pleased to inform you that your **application has made a select**
>   **list of deferrals to** the regular application round.

The text that is in bold looks odd. Can anyone help me clarify whether it's correct or not? If it is correct (*which probably is, since the email came from MIT*), can you please explain the usage of *`has made a select list`* because I've never seen that grammatical structure ever before.

Thank you.

Comment: "Your application has made" is being used to signify that you have made it to the next step, similar to saying "you made it to the first checkpoint" in a race. It's kind of like saying the application process is an obstacle course and your application has made it over the first obstacle. "Select list" refers to a list of applications/people that have been carefully selected alongside you/your application.

Comment: Thanks for your input. See this, "has made a select list", doesn't it sound like there's something missing? Won't it sound better had it been "has made it to a select list"? Let me know what you think :)

Comment: Both are technically correct, but I would say that your suggestion may be a little more clear. "made a select list" is using the same structure that "[make the cut](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/make-the-cut)" uses.

Comment: I'm scratching my head about the question.  To me, the obvious question mark is the use of "deferrals".  Defer means to postpone or to yield, neither of which makes sense in that sentence.

Comment: @Hank: My reading is that "select" is used as an adjective synonymous with "exclusive".

Comment: @grateful Yep, that sounds convincing.

Comment: @fixer1234 the mail was from MIT, so it would be hard to say that the sentence is wrong.

Comment: I agree that this phrasing sounds unnatural. In the sense ‘achieve a place in [a target]’ cited in bib’s answer, there are two constructions: (1) the target is the direct object of _make_ (‘make the news’); (2) the object of _make_ is a generic _it_, and the target is in a prepositional phrase with _to_. To me, construction (1) is limited to definite targets and sounds quite awkward with indefinite ones, whereas (2) is freely usable with either. So “You’ve made the final”, “You’ve made it to the final” and “You’ve made it to a final” are all good; but “You’ve made a final” is awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the meanings of the verb *[make](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/make)* is

> 6.2 Achieve a place in.
>
> *these dogs seldom make the news*
>
> *they made it to the semifinals*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

The phrases *make the list* and *make the cut* are common in AmE.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is correct. The usage of "has made a select list" is also alright. I assume what is odd for you is the usage of word "select" instead of selected. Generally, people use "selected" (selected list in this case). Just see the meaning of the word "select" as an adjective from Merriam-Webster:

adjective  se·lect \sə-ˈlekt\

Definition of select:
 chosen from a number or group by fitness or preference

Thus, using "selected" instead of "select" is totally wrong (e.g., A select number of people are invited).

Also "has made a select list" means that your application is one among the chosen!

Hope I have cleared your doubt. Best regards!